# What is $\arctan(-\tan(\theta))$ equal to?

Tags: trigonometry

I am studying parametrizations, and while trying to prove an inverse function is continuous. I am stuck with the following:

$\arctan(-\tan(\theta))=\arctan(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{-\cos(\theta)})=?$

Question:

What is $\arctan(-\tan(\theta))$ equals to? How do I handle the minus sign?

Comment: $\arctan \tan\theta$ is a sawtooth wave (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), continuous only over $\mathbb{R}\setminus\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}+\pi\mathbb{Z}\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sin(-x) = - \sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$ then
$$\tan(-x) = \frac{\sin(-x)}{\cos(-x)} = - \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = - \tan(x)$$
then
$$\tan^{-1}(- \tan(x)) = \tan^{-1}(\tan(-x)) = -x.$$

Answer (score 5):

Well, $\arctan(-x)=-\arctan x$, because the tangent restricted to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is an odd function and so the same holds for its inverse. Thus you get
$$
\arctan(-\tan(\theta))=-\arctan(\tan(\theta))
$$
which equals $-\theta$ ***provided*** $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to begin with. Otherwise you get $-\theta'$, where $\theta'$ is the only number in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ so that $\theta=\theta'+k\pi$, for some integer $k$.